# Android - ImageView in ListView doesn't show

Tags: android, listview, interface, imageview

I am unable to figure out why ImageView doesn't show up in a ListView

[Left side is the result, Right side is in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi71b.png)

Here is the XML code:

```
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/default_service_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_led"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_led" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLedDisp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_led_display"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_leddisp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSpeaker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_speaker"
        android:foregroundGravity="top|right"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_speaker" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivServo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_servo"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_servo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMotor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_motor"
        android:foregroundGravity="top|right"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_motor" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/default_service_desc" />
```

`

No matter what image I use, from what source... it doesn't show...
I tried to make it invisible and visible again by code and still doesn't work :(

Sorry for the stupid question but it's my first time doing an android application

EDIT1: 
Activity class
   `public class ServiceList extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ListView lvServices;
private ServiceAdaptor adaptor;
private List<Service> mServicesList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_list);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = database.getReference();
    DatabaseReference servicesRef = rootRef.child("services");


    lvServices = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mListView_services);
    mServicesList = new ArrayList<>();



    servicesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (mServicesList.size() > 0)
                mServicesList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot id : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Service service = id.getValue(Service.class);
                mServicesList.add(service);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's WORKING!" + service, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            adaptor = new ServiceAdaptor(getApplicationContext(),mServicesList);
            lvServices.setAdapter(adaptor);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            String error = databaseError.getDetails();
        }
    });`
```

with the firebase, I change only the TextViews, the images are not touched

EDIT2:

Service.java

```
public class Service {
private int id;
private String name = "Name";
private String desc = "Description";
private boolean led = false;
private boolean ledDisplay = false;
private boolean servo = false;
private boolean motor = false;
private boolean speaker = false;


public Service() {
}

//Constructors
public Service(String name, String desc, boolean led, boolean ledDisplay, boolean servo, boolean motor, boolean speaker) {
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.led = led;
    this.ledDisplay = ledDisplay;
    this.servo = servo;
    this.motor = motor;
    this.speaker = speaker;
}

//Set/Get

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public boolean isLed() {
    return led;
}

public void setLed(boolean led) {
    this.led = led;
}

public boolean isLedDisplay() {
    return ledDisplay;
}

public void setLedDisplay(boolean ledDisplay) {
    this.ledDisplay = ledDisplay;
}

public boolean isServo() {
    return servo;
}

public void setServo(boolean servo) {
    this.servo = servo;
}

public boolean isMotor() {
    return motor;
}

public void setMotor(boolean motor) {
    this.motor = motor;
}

public boolean isSpeaker() {
    return speaker;
}

public void setSpeaker(boolean speaker) {
    this.speaker = speaker;
}
}
```

and ServiceAdaptor.java

```
public class ServiceAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<Service> mServicesList;

//Constructors


public ServiceAdaptor(Context mContext, List<Service> mServicesList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mServicesList = mServicesList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mServicesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mServicesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.services, null);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvDesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
    ImageView ivLed = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivLed);
    ImageView ivLedDisp = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivLedDisp);
    ImageView ivServo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivServo);
    ImageView ivMotor = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivMotor);
    ImageView ivSpeaker = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivSpeaker);

    tvName.setText(mServicesList.get(position).getName());
    tvDesc.setText(mServicesList.get(position).getDesc());
    if (!mServicesList.get(position).isLed()) ivLed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (!mServicesList.get(position).isLedDisplay()) ivLedDisp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (!mServicesList.get(position).isServo()) ivServo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (!mServicesList.get(position).isMotor()) ivMotor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (!mServicesList.get(position).isSpeaker()) ivSpeaker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    v.setTag(mServicesList.get(position).getId());

    return v;
}
}
```

and this is the data that it's receiving

```
`{  "services" : [ null, { "desc" : "Playing the speaker",
                           "led" : false,
                           "ledDisp" : false,
                           "motor" : false,
                           "name" : "Sing",
                           "servo" : false,
                           "speaker" : true},

                         { "desc" : "1322",
                           "led" : true,
                           "ledDisp" : true,
                           "motor" : false,
                           "name" : "Mike",
                           "servo" : false,
                           "speaker" : false
                          } ]
}`
```

Just to check if the boolean check is working I changed the visibility of the images to just change the color of the TextView and that worked, so the problem is with the images

Comment: I don't have screenshots to help you debug, but the most likely cause is that  your textview and the first image are pushing your second image out of the Linearlayout's bounds. A hint to help you to debug this: on android studio open Tools > Android > Layout Inspector. There you can see the whole hierarchy of views. Try to find the image and check if it is in fact pushed out of the frame

Comment: The images show up in the hierarchy, but I don't see them at all in the preview window :( .... I set the visibility of both TextView to invisible or gone, and the images still don't show up, so i guess they are not pushed out of the screen

Comment: Show your activity class, layout seems to be alright.

Comment: @tahsinRupam editted the main post for the activity class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace it with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Hello, world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/editText"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If it doesn't work, I'll give you another suggestion.

Comment: okay, now i see that you have a list view (I didn't see it in your layout file). Either your listview is occupying the whole screen and thus covering the rest of the views or your textviews and imageviews are inside the listview, which is a mistake. If you want to put your text and images inside a view that can be scrolled horizontally, move them to a scrollview.

Comment: But if I change ListView to ScrollView, then I have no idea how to instantiate that layout to make a list from firebase database

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts a little bit. Listview is a layout that adapts data into the screen. You get the data from somewhere, like a list of phone contacts for example, and then add an adapter to it to define how each element should be displayed in the screen (textviews, etc). In your case, all I saw is statically defined views. It's an entire different story

Comment: I am using Google's real-time database to get a list of 'persons', for every person i want to get the name, description and some booleans that can be changed at any time.. The changes takes place when every are changed in the database, but i can't go forward because i can't get the imeges to show (even if they are static)

Comment: Right. The problem however is that your text and imageviews for every item need to be generated in the adapter that you set to the listview. That's the whole purpose of an adapter: take data and decide how to show it. For what I understood in your question, you are adding the layout directly to the activity. If you did that, it won't work. If you confirm that this is what you did, and if you need help with the adapter, let me know and I'll change my answer to help you do it (paste your ServiceAdapter class however)

Comment: Posted the Service class, the adaptor class and the data the application is getting from firebase database